# Options for cursor / caret positioning in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, editor

I've started to use Eclipse for C++ coding recently and I have problems with the caret / cursor positioning (when using CTRL + LEFT / RIGHT arrows). The cursor jumps through characters very non-intuitive ways. The only related option I found was "Smart caret positioning at line start and end" but thats not it. Are there any other options or plugins for this? If not, do you think it is possible to make a plugin that changes the way CTRL+LEFT/RIGHT works?

Comment: Navigate to *Preferences->C/C++->Editor*. Uncheck *Smart caret positioning in identifiers*. This will get rid of the camelCase stops, but I know of no way to get rid of underscore stops.